# Drawing a flag on Google Maps using Drawing Manager doesn't give exact location

Tags: google-maps

I'm using Google Maps drawing manager, when I draw an icon (flag) it doesn't show on the map as expected, I expect to see the flag exactly in the same location of the mouse click, but in my case it is far, any idea why?

[image]

Drawing Manager settings:

```
      var drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager({
                    drawingMode: google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.MARKER,
                    drawingControl: true,
                    drawingMode: null,
                    drawingControlOptions: {
                        position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER,
                        drawingModes: ['marker', 'circle', 'polygon', 'polyline', 'rectangle']
                    }
                });
```

Comment: why are you using drawing manager for the marker?

Comment: Because I draw all kind of shapes and routes on the map, I want to give a simple example from the problem, and is that matter, it a problem that exists!!

Comment: I removed the custom marker from the code example because it also reproduced without the custom marker.

Comment: <div id="map"> in iframe will fix the click event position : https://stackoverflow.com/a/40725524/315264

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the description of [Custom Markers in the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/custom-markers).

If you look at [Google's example that uses that icon](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/icon-complex), you will see the correct parameters to put the "staff" of the flag at the defined coordinates:

```
// Origins, anchor positions and coordinates of the marker increase in the X
// direction to the right and in the Y direction down.
var image = {
  url: 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/images/beachflag.png',
  // This marker is 20 pixels wide by 32 pixels high.
  size: new google.maps.Size(20, 32),
  // The origin for this image is (0, 0).
  origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
  // The anchor for this image is the base of the flagpole at (0, 32).
  anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 32)
};
```

Use it in the marker creation like this:

```
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: {lat: beach[1], lng: beach[2]},
    map: map,
    icon: image,
    shape: shape,
    title: beach[0],
    zIndex: beach[3]
  });
```

Or in the `MarkerOptions` property of the `DrawingManager` like this:

```
markerOptions: {
  icon: {
    url: 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/images/beachflag.png',
    // This marker is 20 pixels wide by 32 pixels high.
    size: new google.maps.Size(20, 32),
    // The origin for this image is (0, 0).
    origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
    // The anchor for this image is the base of the flagpole at (0, 32).
    anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 32)
  }
},
```

[proof of concept fiddle (based on Google's DrawingManager example)](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/jk3u7xh8/)

[image: screenshot]

**code snippet (based on Google's DrawingManager example):**

```js
function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {
      lat: -34.397,
      lng: 150.644
    },
    zoom: 8
  });

  var drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager({
    drawingMode: google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.MARKER,
    drawingControl: true,
    drawingControlOptions: {
      position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER,
      drawingModes: ['marker', 'circle', 'polygon', 'polyline', 'rectangle']
    },
    markerOptions: {
      icon: {
        url: 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/images/beachflag.png',
        // This marker is 20 pixels wide by 32 pixels high.
        size: new google.maps.Size(20, 32),
        // The origin for this image is (0, 0).
        origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
        // The anchor for this image is the base of the flagpole at (0, 32).
        anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 32)
      }
    },
    circleOptions: {
      fillColor: '#ffff00',
      fillOpacity: 1,
      strokeWeight: 5,
      clickable: false,
      editable: true,
      zIndex: 1
    }
  });
  drawingManager.setMap(map);
}
```

```css
#map {
  height: 100%;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=drawing&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
```