# Google Map dragging not working in iframe

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I`m trying to render a map on a page that will be scaled to fit in a users window.
The issue with scaling was wrong coordinates on click events.
This solution fixed that:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/40725524

But now dragging stopped working.
Is there a easy fix for this? Or might there be a better way of handling a map in a scaled container?

Fiddle showing the issue:
https://jsfiddle.net/vdjeLouc/

```
<iframe id=iframe src="" width="640" height="480"></iframe>
```

```
const iframe = document.getElementById('iframe');
iframe.contentWindow.document.open();
iframe.contentWindow.document.write('<div id="map" style="width: 100%; height: 100%"></div>');
iframe.contentWindow.document.close();

const mapContainer = iframe.contentWindow.document.querySelector('#map');
const map = new google.maps.Map(mapContainer, {
  center: {lat: 50, lng: 10},
  zoom: 5
});
```

Comment: Why are you using an iframe??

Comment: Because that was the only solution i found to give correct coordinates on click events when the div is scaled.

Comment: Why do you need to scale it + your code doesn't reflect that you are using a CSS scale transform.

Comment: believe me, i have a perfectly legitimate use for an iframe with a Google map and i don't think i should have to explain "why". i'm having this issue too (along with others) and cannot find a solution past "it's a bug".